# Find out difference between date in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide, selenium-grid

try to find out difference between date in selenium webdriver example start time: Jul 21 2016 10:50AM and Endtime:Jul 21 2016  8:20PM

Comment: calculating time difference is not selenium problem. The solution depends on the programming language you use

Comment: i m using java with selenium

Answer (score 0):

This is solution for java 8:

First, define format of the datetime:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM dd yyyy h:mma");
```

Then store your datetimes:

```
LocalDateTime startTime = LocalDateTime.parse("Jul 21 2016 10:50AM", formatter);
LocalDateTime endTime = LocalDateTime.parse("Jul 21 2016 8:20PM", formatter);
```

And calculate the difference:

```
Duration difference = Duration.between(startTime, endTime);
```

You can get difference in various units, for example minutes:

```
System.out.println(difference.toMinutes());
```

Comment: String time_in = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='tb']/tbody/tr[" + i + "]/td[3]")).getText();
String time_out = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='tb']/tbody/tr[" + i + "]/td[4]")).getText();
     
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd yyyy h:mmaa");  
java.util.Date util_StartDate = formatter.parse(time_in);
java.sql.Time sql_StartDate = new java.sql.Time(util_StartDate.getTime());
java.util.Date util_EndDate = formatter.parse(time_out);
java.sql.Time sql_EndDate = new java.sql.Time( util_EndDate.getTime() );

Comment: It works perfect for example from your question. You commented another code, another date libraries. I have written this is solution for java 8.